# toFixed and replace doesn't seems to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and javascript, I would like to make it increase every milliseconds and replace each digit with a span, it seems like replacing the span is working but `toFixed` is causing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
function getValueTotal(){
    var strAnn = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../a/getTotal',
        data: {info:4},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function(data){
        if(data.status == '0'){
            if(data.d.value=="0"){
                strAnn = 8414735;   
            }else{
                strAnn = data.d.value;
            }           
        }else{
            strAnn = 29451147;
        }
        $("#pTotal").html(strAnn);
            $('#pTotal').countTo({
                format: 'money',
                from: strAnn,
                to: 999999999.99,
                speed: 100000000,
                refresh_interval: 0.00001,
                on_complete: function(value) {
                    $(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });

    });
}

(function($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refresh_interval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;
        return $(this).each(function() {
            var _this = this,
                loop_count = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(update_timer, options.refresh_interval);
            function update_timer() {
                value += increment;
                loop_count++;
                if(options.format == 'money') {
                  //  $(_this).html('$' + number_with_commas(value.toFixed(options.decimals)));
                  var valueData =  $(_this).value.toFixed(options.decimals);
                  $(_this).html('$' + valueData.replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g , ' <span class="some-number">$1</span>'));

                } else {
                    $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));
                }
                if(typeof(options.on_update) == 'function') {
                    options.on_update.call(_this, value);
                }
                if(loop_count >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;
                    if(typeof(options.on_complete) == 'function') {
                        options.on_complete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    };
    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,
        to: 100,
        speed: 1000,
        refresh_interval: 100,
        decimals: 2,
        on_update: null,
        on_complete: null
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
var valueData =  $(_this).value.toFixed(options.decimals);
```

To

```
var valueData =  parseFloat($(_this).value);
 if(!isNaN(valueData)){
   valueData = valueData.toFixed(options.decimals);
 }
```

The value is string and there is no toFixed function in the string object.
And also be aware that the value is not a number it will throw an exception.

Comment: @MuthaFury because your value is not a number.I edited the answer

Comment: Let's assume, if the value is 29451147.324234, how to make it to 2 decimal number?

Comment: var value = 29451147.324234;
value = value.toFixed(2);
So first you must be sure that your value is a number

Comment: now I received this error "valueData.replace is not a function"

Comment: replace method is working on strings.
1. For using toFixed on the variable, the variable must be a number
2. For using replace on the variable, the variable must be a string.

Comment: So for replace, I need to convert the toFixed result to string?

Comment: @MuthaFury I don't know what logic your code use, but if you want to replace something it must be a string.

Comment: Apparently, I just put this and it works fine lol

var valueData = value.toFixed(options.decimals);